# Testing tools for a front-end HTML5 app

Tags: tools, ios

I've got an offline app that has been built on HTML/CSS/JS and it runs only on 'iPad iOS 8.4' within a wrapper application.

The interactions are very simple: You can go from page to page and you can have any UI elements that a website can have, but being an offline app you cannot have any HTTP request and any dependencies must be included within the directory containing the `.html` file.

The structure of the app is: Each HTML page is its own standalone directory so any dependencies must be included within that directory.

Production Dir structure looks like this:

```
page1
  |--page1.html
  |--style.css
  |--scripts.js

page2
  |--page2.html
  |--style.css
  |--scripts.js
```

There is no way for **page1** to use any of the dependencies that **page2** have and vice-a-versa, its just the way the app works.

I used **grunt** to build this app in a way one would build a website and then produced the folder structure you see above.

So I don't have to update styles in every folder if there is a global change

Development folder structure looks like this:

```
 app
  |--page1
      |--page1.html
  |--page2
      |--page2.html
  |--sass
      |--styles.scss
  |--javascript
      |--page1.js
      |--page2.js
```

What tools/frameworks can I use to test an application like this, where I don't need to do cross browser testing only testing on an iOS device iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Run the App in an iOS simulator that comes with Xcode, then test with selenium.

https://techblog.polteq.com/en/running-tests-on-a-xcode-iphone-simulator-3/

What you also could consider is using Appium, which is quite similar to selenium.
Included blogpost has a very detailed explanation.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/antino/archive/2014/09/22/how-to-set-up-a-basic-working-appium-test-environment.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which type of testing you want to do. If you want to do [automated functional testing](http://www.ranorex.com/automated-functional-testing.html), I can recommend Ranorex.

With this tool you can directly record tests on your iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Install Firefox and the SeleniumIDE plug and write simple automated tests with it.

Export to a programming language such as C#, Ruby or Python as desired.